# FormControlName TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, formgroups

I have one dropdown item in my ionic project

**home.html**

```
   <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label  color="danger">Location</ion-label>
            <ion-select  name="location"  formControlName="location" >
                <ion-option   value=3>{{'Palarivattom'}}</ion-option>
                <ion-option   value=4>{{'Kadavantra'}}</ion-option>
                <ion-option   value=5>{{'Kaloor'}}</ion-option>

            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
```

Used formgroup to create the form 
**home.ts**

```
{
   this.formgroup=formbuilder.group({
    mobile:['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
              Validators.minLength(10,), Validators.maxLength(10)])],
    password:['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
              Validators.minLength(5)])],

    location:['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],

});
this.mobile=this.formgroup.controls['mobile'];
this.password=this.formgroup.controls['password'];
this.location=this.formgroup.controls['loaction'];
 }
```

When tried to get the location value getting error message as 'undefined'

```
doprint() {

console.log( this.name.value)   //Ajith
console.log(this.email.value)    //ajith@gmail.com
console.log(this.location.value) //undefined
}
```

Comment: Is the typo 'loaction' by mistake in `this.location=this.formgroup.controls['loaction'];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo

```
this.location=this.formgroup.controls['location'];
```

Anyway standard way to do is,

```
doprint() {
let formItem = this.itemForm.value;
console.log(formItem.name);
console.log(name.email);
console.log(name.location) ;
}
```